# how to save data in xml using windows 8.1 mobile app

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

when i click save button data is not saving in xml file

```
private const string XmlFile = "Order.xml";
private async void btncalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ClsOrder ord = new ClsOrder();
            ord.Id = 1;
            ord.package = str;
            ord.Domestic = strchk;

            List<ClsOrder> ordlist = await getXmlorderlist();
            ordlist.Add(ord);

            using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(XmlFile, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<ClsOrder>));
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, ordlist);
            }
}
private async Task<List<ClsOrder>> getXmlorderlist()
        {
            await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(XmlFile, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(XmlFile);
            if (stream.Length == 0)
                return new List<ClsOrder>();
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<ClsOrder>));
            List<ClsOrder> ordlist = (List<ClsOrder>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            return ordlist;
        }
```

How to save data in xml file.??
This code is not working..
I have taken all the data in list `List<ClsOrder> ordlist`,I want to save data in xml.

Comment: What does 'not working' actually mean?

Comment: my list value not save in order.xml so how can i do it?

Comment: OK, what does 'not save' mean? Do you get an exception? Is the file blank? Is the file the same as it was before? Is the file missing?

Comment: sir my data store in list and list data save in xml file this file name is order.xml i mean write in xml file but issue is how to save list value in xml file

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, I just don't understand what isn't working. You have code to add an item to the list and save it back to the same file you read it from - what part of that isn't working?

Comment: using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(XmlFile, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<ClsOrder>));
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, ordlist);
            }

Comment: this part not working and also here not any error show. so what should i do?

Comment: Yes, but as I keep asking: *what does not working mean?*. What is in your file after you write it?

Comment: serializer.WriteObject(stream, ordlist); this part should write in xml file but this code not write in xml file.